# Get two array values alternately

Tags: perl

I'm writing two array contents to file:

```perl
@a1 = ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI');
@b1 = (1234, 6789, 7635);

open my $fh, ">", "log.txt" or die "Cannot open log.txt: $!";

foreach ( @a1, @a2 ) {
    print $fh "$_\n";
} 

close $fh;
```

Output:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
1234
6789
7635
```

I want to write it to the log file in the following manner:

```
ABC 1234
DEF 6789
GHI 7635
```

I'm unsure how to achieve it.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=500644

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pairwise` operator from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)

Like so

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::MoreUtils 'pairwise';

my @a1 = qw/ ABC  DEF  GHI  /;
my @b1 = qw/ 1234 6789 7635 /;

my @pairs = pairwise { [ $a, $b ] } @a1, @b1;

print "@$_\n" for @pairs;
```

#### output

```
ABC 1234
DEF 6789
GHI 7635
```

If this is *all* you want to do with the pairs then you may avoid the intermediate list altogether and write

```
pairwise { print "$a $b\n" } @a1, @b1;
```

with the same result

Note that if one array is shorter than the other then `$a` or `$b` will be set to `undef` after the end of the shorter array. You will have to handle that as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Provided that `@a1` and `@b1` are always the same length:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a1 = qw( ABC DEF GHI );
my @b1 = qw( 1234 6789 7635 );

open my $fh, ">", "log.txt" or die "Cannot open log.txt: $!"; 

for my $i (0..$#a1){
    print $fh "$a1[$i] $b1[$i]\n";
}
```

Or:

```
use feature qw/ say /;

say $fh join(' ', $a1[$_], $b1[$_]) for 0 .. $#a1;
```

Comment: Tabs are such awful things

Comment: Tried this option too and worked fine. Thanks much !